# Razor Pages ASP.NET Core 6 - How to add background image with blur

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have successfully added a "background-image" to my Razor Pages application.

Now, when using "filter: blur(2px);" the header and footer blur, but not the image.

I've been at this for hours, saw tons of threads on how to add the image, but couldn't find a way to do this properly (the blur), or see someone else experiencing the same behavior.

My _Layout:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - LifeCompanion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/LifeCompanion.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm bg-transparent border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            LifeCompanion
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                            <li>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" type="button" asp-page="/LActions/ImageManagement">
                                    Images!
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2022 - LifeCompanion - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS - using site.css to apply changes globally - is:

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    background: url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
```

So far so good.

Now when adding to my css:

```css
body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    background: url(../img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

The footer and header blurs, but not the background-image as anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `filter: blur(2px);` with `backdrop-filter: blur(2px);`.

Answer (score 0):

`filter` will affect the element itself, and `backdrop-filter` will affect the elements beneath the element within the bounding box of the element.So in your project, you need to use `backdrop-filter`. You can follow this [link](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/backdrop-filter/) to learn more about `backdrop-filter`.